# Hyperthreading: is there a way to know from the command line if it is enabled in BIOS?

Tags: bios

Is there a way to know from the command line of a standard LINUX distro (or by installing some tool), whether hyperthreading is enabled in the BIOS of a given machine ?

Answer (score 5):

`util-linux`'s `lscpu` shows whether hyper-threading is enabled (or anything similar):

```
$ lscpu
[...]
Thread(s) per core:    2
[...]
```

2 or more in the "Thread(s) per core" line means hyper-threading is enabled.

(You'll also see `ht` in the flags in `/proc/cpuinfo`, but that only means that the processor supports hyper-threading.)